# How to avoid a class cast exception between Windows and MacOS?

Tags: java, windows, macos, filechooser

We develop a Java application under a Windows environment (OpenJDK17 for Windows), but recently it was requested to make sure everything works under MacOS.
Even though it is a Java application, some things might happen and it did.

When I try to export a file, the file chooser being used (BasicFileChooser) works without problems under Windows and Ubuntu Linux, but the same action under MacOS, causes a class cast exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> class com.apple.laf.AquaFileChooserUI cannot be cast to class javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI
> (com.apple.laf.AquaFileChooserUI and javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')

You might be thinking why don't I just use JFileChooser, but unfortunately I need to be able to get the GUI and update the name of the file in the text field on the fly.

For that, I have the following code:
//fileName is global variable here...
`Utilities.invokeLater(() -> ((BasicFileChooserUI) getUI()).setFileName(fileName));`

So you see, I need the "getUI()" from the FileChooser so I can have access to the "setFileName" method.

Any simple workaround would be enough.
I wanted this:

```
if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
    val osType = doPrivileged(getOSTypeAction());
    if (osType == WINDOWS || osType == LINUX) {
      invokeLater(() -> ((BasicFileChooserUI) getUI()).setFileName(fileName));
    }
    if (osType == MACOSX) {
      invokeLater(() -> ((AquaFileChooserUI) getUI()).setFileName(fileName));
    }
 }
```

But I can't call "AquaFileChooserUI" from a Windows JDK.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _Even though it is a Java application, some things might happen and it did_ => Java guarantees that the same code can run on different environments because all the platform boilerplate to interact with the hosting system is left to the JVM. But here you're acting on the OS-specific implementations, not on their interfaces, so indeed the cross-platform power of Java is lost - but because you deliberately chose to lose it :)

Comment: Do you really need the UI?  Does [setSelectedFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile(java.io.File)) not work?

Comment: Always state your Java GUI framework of choice: Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, assuming the method is named the same on all platforms:

```
Object ui = getUI();
Method method = ui.getClass().getMethod("setFileName", String.class);
method.invoke(ui, fileName);
```

Comment: If AquaFileChooserUI is not even compatible with BasicFileChooserUI, there are chances the methods are not called the same way. If AquaFileChooserUI is not/cannot be available in your class loader then clearly you have no other option than going through reflection (probably with some tricks like "try first setFileName and if not there then try the Mac equivalent), but if it is, I'd rather do an instanceof of what you get from getUI() and cast/invoke accordingly